# Cuda reuse of shared memory variable name

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I have two cuda kernels that are run, one after the other:

```
__global__
void calculate_histo(const float* const d_logLuminance,
        unsigned int* d_histogram,
        float min_logLum,
        float lumRange,
        int numBins,
        int num_elements){
    extern __shared__ float sdata[];
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int bid = blockIdx.x;
    int gid = tid * blockDim.x + bid;

    // load input into __shared__ memory
    if(gid < num_elements)
    {
        sdata[tid] = d_logLuminance[gid];
        __syncthreads();

        //compute bin value of input
        int bin = static_cast <int> (floor((d_logLuminance[gid]-min_logLum)/ lumRange * numBins));
        //increment histogram at bin value
        atomicAdd(&(d_histogram[bin]), 1);
    }
}

__global__
void blelloch_scan(unsigned int* const d_cdf, unsigned int* d_histogram, int numBins) {
    extern __shared__ unsigned int sdata[];// allocated on invocation
    int thid = threadIdx.x;
    //printf("%i \n", thid);
    //printf("%i \n", d_histogram[thid]);

    int offset = 1;


    sdata[2*thid] = d_histogram[2*thid]; // load input into shared memory
    sdata[2*thid+1] = d_histogram[2*thid+1];

    // build sum in place up the tree
    for (int d = numBins>>1; d > 0; d >>= 1) {
        __syncthreads();
        if (thid < d) {
            int ai = offset*(2*thid+1)-1;
            int bi = offset*(2*thid+2)-1;
            sdata[bi] += sdata[ai];
        }
        offset *= 2;
    }
    if (thid == 0) { sdata[numBins - 1] = 0; } // clear the last element
    // traverse down tree & build scan
    for (int d = 1; d < numBins; d *= 2) {
        offset >>= 1;
        __syncthreads();
        if (thid < d) {
            int ai = offset*(2*thid+1)-1;
            int bi = offset*(2*thid+2)-1;
            float t = sdata[ai];
            sdata[ai] = sdata[bi];
            sdata[bi] += t;
        }
        __syncthreads();
        d_cdf[2*thid] = sdata[2*thid]; // write results to device memory
        d_cdf[2*thid+1] = sdata[2*thid+1];
    }

}
```

They both use shared memory. The second has an `unsigned int` array as the shared memory. The first has a `float array`. I thought I should be able to reuse the same variable name, `sdata`, for both arrays, since shared memory is cleared after each kernel launch, but I'm getting the error:

```
declaration is incompatible with previous 'sdata'
```

If I use different variable names for each kernel, that seems to solve the problem. Anyone know why I can't reuse the same variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA is just following the rule of the standard C language. Quoting the Kernighan and Ritchie  "The C Programming Language" book:

> An external variable must be defined, exactly once, outside of any function; this sets aside storage for it. The variable must also be declared in each function that wants to access it; this states the type of the variable. [...] *Definition* refers to the place where the variable is created or assigned storage; *declaration* refers to places where the nature of the variable is stated but no storage is allocated.

Somewhere in your program you should have something like

```
extern __shared__ unsigned int sdata[];
```

At that location, you are *creating* a pointer, named `sdata`, to an `unsigned int`. Inside the `__global__` functions you are *declaring* the type of `sdata`, so that the `__global__` function can be aware of it. In the

```
kernel<<<blocks,threads,numbytes_for_shared>>>(...);
```

launch, you are allocating space of the array pointed to by `sdata`.

Comment: I doubt this is actually the case, as you can encounter this problem even without having sdata[] in two separate functions; and, sdata is not really an extern variable which has some global definition.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are saying?

Comment: @einpoklum The problem in your question appears to be exactly the same as the problem in this question. CUDA deals with `extern` variables the same way as C++ does.