# Getting CUDA error "declaration is incompatible with previous "variable_name"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cuda, initialization, gpu-shared-memory

I'm trying to compile a program including a kernel with MSVS 2012 and CUDA. I use shared memory, but unlike in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338679/cuda-reuse-of-shared-memory-variable-name) regarding the same problem, I only use my variable name for this kernel's shared memory once, so there's no issue of redefinition. With code like this:

```
template<typename T>
__global__ void mykernel(
    const T* __restrict__ data,
    T*       __restrict__ results) 
{
    extern __shared__ T warp_partial_results[];
    /* ... */
    warp_partial_results[lane_id] = something;
    /* ... */
    results[something_else] = warp_partial_results[something_else];
    /* ... */
}
```

which is instantiated for several types (e.g. float, int, unsigned int), I get the dreaded

> ```
> declaration is incompatible with previous "warp_partial_results"
> ```

message. What could cause this?

Comment: voting to close, you haven't provided a SSCCE.org code.  SO expects: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. " There's no exclusion for "conceptual questions about problems with my code" or "what could possibly cause this" type questions.  Provide a complete, compilable code that demonstrates the problem, along with the compile command you are using with it.

Comment: Will add code in a couple of minutes.

Comment: The code you've shown so far is not complete.  When I try to hack it into a compilable code, it does not give any compile error for me.  Please study the [SSCCE.org webpage](http://sscce.org) and provide a *complete*, *compilable* code that demonstrates the error.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I couldn't quite share my actual code out in the open. However, I found the solution myself, see below.

Comment: Nobody asked for your actual code.  Just a reproducer, which is quite trivial to create to demonstrate this.  Glad you found a solution.  To be clear, your first sentence says "CUDA doesn't immediately support `__shared__` memory arrays...".  Although it's pretty obvious from your answer, it would be more precise to say the issue is with "*dynamically allocated* `__shared__` mmemory arrays..."  Statically allocated arrays work just fine in templated functions, even with multiple instantiations.

Comment: @JackOLantern [here](http://pastebin.com/3UTr5U08) is an example code that shows the problem.  The solution is actually covered in the [CUDA simple templates sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-templates), the description of which is: "This sample is a templatized version of the template project. It also shows how to correctly templatize dynamically allocated shared memory arrays. "

Comment: @RobertCrovella It seems that this is not a CUDA related problem and that I recreate it by this [code](http://pastebin.com/f91Uudut). The two kernel (or function) calls relate to two different type declarations of the `extern` variable, so the compiler is expecting two different definitions outside the functions for the same symbol. I would say that _CUDA doesn't immediately support shared memory arrays in templated functions, as it (apparently) generates actual definitions of those extern's_ is misleading for the first and incorrect for the second part (it does not generate, it expects).

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I'm sorry, I did not have time to properly edit my question so far. Hopefully tomorrow morning. Anyway, editing the answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: C++ compilers generate separate functions for each type templated function use is used at. This is why use of templates can increase the size of the generated object files. I don't think this is actually too different from the question you linked (and I think your comment on the answer is a bit inaccurate).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CUDA doesn't immediately 'support' dynamically-allocated shared memory arrays in templated functions, as it (apparently) generates actual definitions of those extern's. If you instantiate a templated function for multiple types, the definitions would conflict.

A workaround is available in the form of template specialization via classes. You can choose either NVIDIA's implementation, or a nicer convenient one mentioned below.

#### The NVIDIA implementation

See:

[http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/wiki/ParallelComputingSpring2015/cuda/nvidia/samples/0_Simple/simpleTemplates/sharedmem.cuh](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/%7Ewrf/wiki/ParallelComputingSpring2015/cuda/nvidia/samples/0_Simple/simpleTemplates/sharedmem.cuh)

You use the workaround as follows:

```
template<class T> __global__ void foo( T* g_idata, T* g_odata)
{
    // shared memory
    // the size is determined by the host application
    
    SharedMem<T> shared;
    T* sdata = shared.getPointer();

    // .. the rest of the code remains unchanged!
}
```

the `getPointer()` has<sup>*</sup> a specialized implementation for every type, which returns a different pointer, e.g. `extern __shared__ float* shared_mem_float` or `extern __shared__ int* shared_mem_int` etc.

#### A nicer implementation

In my own [cuda-kat](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-kat/) library, there's a facility for that. You just write:

```
auto foo = kat::shared_memory::dynamic::proxy<T>();
```

and `foo` is a `T*` to your shared memory. You can also write:

```
auto n = kat::shared_memory::dynamic::size<T>();
```

which gets you the number of elements of type T fitting into the allocated dynamic shared memory.

Naturally, I'm partial to my own solution, so - choose whatever works for you.

---

<sub>(*) - Not really. in NVidia's supplied header file they specialize for some basic types and that's that.</sub>